# Sending email using Java, connecting to a gmail host hangs

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I would like to send emails via Java code. I added in my library the following .JARs:  log4j.jar, smtp.jar, mailapi.jar,ctivation.jar. And my Java class looks like this:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{    
   String to = "abcd@gmail.com";
   String from = "web@gmail.com";
   String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();


   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

   SmtpAuthenticator authentication = new SmtpAuthenticator();
   javax.mail.Message msg = new MimeMessage(Session
                       .getInstance(properties, authentication));

   try {
       msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
       msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
           new InternetAddress(to));
       msg.setSubject("Subject");
       msg.setText("Working fine..!");
       System.out.println("fine1    !!");
       Transport transport = Session.getDefaultInstance( properties , null).getTransport("smtp");
       System.out.println("fine2    !!");
       transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 465 , "username", "password");
       System.out.println("fine3    !!");
       Transport.send(msg);
       System.out.println("fine!!");
   }
   catch(Exception exc) {
       System.out.println(exc);
   }
}
}
```

My SmtpAuthenticator class:

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;

public class SmtpAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public SmtpAuthenticator() {

        super();
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        String username = "user";
        String password = "password";
        if ((username != null) && (username.length() > 0) && (password != null)
                && (password.length() > 0)) {

            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When i run my Java application class it prints: 
fine1   !!
fine2   !!

And it hangs. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Check that you don't have a firewall blocking the communication between your pc/server and the external smtp server.

Comment: The Firewall is set to notify me when Windows Firewall Blocks a new program on home and public networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 465 , "username", "password");
```

465 is the port for smtp over ssl (smtps), so either use port 25:

```
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 25 , "username", "password");
```

or change to use smtps

```
Transport transport = Session.getDefaultInstance( properties , null).getTransport("smtps");

transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 465, "username", "password");
```

Comment: It has problems again, i tried with your both suggestions. Result: fine1 !!
fine2 !!
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. z5sm47598012eee.31 - gsmtp

Comment: Do you have two step verification enabled for your Gmail account? It won't work if you do

Comment: I have only the things which I posted.

Comment: Two step verification is setup through gmail - not in code. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en 
If you have this enabled on your account your code wont work. The fact you get an authenication exception implies you tried too many times with perhaps wrong password so you got locked out

Comment: No, i don't have but this does not work. For me SMTP host does not matter (it is not important to be gmail) i just want to make sending mail working...

Comment: Hey, i managed to solve my problem. I need to set POP in my email client (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en). Thanks for advices.

Comment: Also this article http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/ was very useful.